# aws lambda sending a timed http request

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS lambda.
Will like to seek advice from the experts here.
I understand that Lambda is activated based on a trigger. 
If I wanted to send a timed http request (for example, send a http request 4 hours later), 
is there any recommendations to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can configure scheduled AWS Lambda Triggers using Cloudwatch.

[Tutorial: Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

> To create a rule using the console
>
> 1. Open the CloudWatch console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/
> 2. In the navigation pane, choose Events, Create rule.
> 3. For Event Source, do the following:
>
>    a. Choose Schedule.
>
>    b. Choose Fixed rate of and specify the schedule interval (for example, 5 minutes).
> 4. For Targets, choose Add target, Lambda function.
> 5. For Function, select the Lambda function that you created.
> 6. Choose Configure details.
> 7. For Rule definition, type a name and description for the rule.
> 8. Choose Create rule.